# Java- How to create Java Hashtable from HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashtable

I want to Create Java Hashtable from HashMap.

```
 HashMap hMap = new HashMap();       
//populate HashMap
hMap.put("1","One");
hMap.put("2","Two");
hMap.put("3","Three");

//create new Hashtable
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();

//populate Hashtable
ht.put("1","This value would be REPLACED !!");
ht.put("4","Four");
```

After this what will be the easiest procedure?

Comment: `Hashtable ht = new Hashtable(hMap);` or `ht.putAll(hMap);`. Use the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html). Also, you should use generics and not use [raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: Yes but I am bound to follow the requirement. @AndyTurner thanks friend

Comment: OK @Jesper got it thanks friend

Comment: Why do you want to use a `Hashtable`?

Comment: hashtable ,raw types? can you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Hashtable` constructor that accepts a `Map` :

```
public Hashtable(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> t)
```

And also you should favor generic types on raw types and program by interface as you declare your `Map` instances:

```
Map<String,String> hMap = new HashMap<>();       
//populate HashMap
hMap.put("1","One");
hMap.put("2","Two");
hMap.put("3","Three");

//create new Hashtable
Map<String,String> ht = new Hashtable<>(hMap);
```

Comment: @Minati Das: `Enumeration` is as outdated as `Hashtable `, but if you really need it, use the [`Collections.enumeration` bridge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#enumeration-java.util.Collection-), e.g. instead of `hashtable.keys()`, you can use `Collections .enumeration(map.keySet())` and instead of `hashtable.elements()`, you can use `Collections.enumeration(map.values())`. But normally you use an `Iterator` or just a for-each loop, `for(String key: map.keySet()) …` or `for(String value: map.values()) …`

Answer (score 0):

Whoomp!! I have done successfully.. here it is :)

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CreateHashtableFromHashMap {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create HashMap
    HashMap hMap = new HashMap();

    //populate HashMap
    hMap.put("1","One");
    hMap.put("2","Two");
    hMap.put("3","Three");

    //create new Hashtable
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();

    //populate Hashtable
    ht.put("1","This value would be REPLACED !!");
    ht.put("4","Four");

    //print values of Hashtable before copy from HashMap
    System.out.println("hastable contents displaying before copy");
    Enumeration e = ht.elements();
    while(e.hasMoreElements())
    System.out.println(e.nextElement());

    ht.putAll(hMap);

    //Display contents of Hashtable
    System.out.println("hashtable contents displaying after copy");
    e = ht.elements();
    while(e.hasMoreElements())
    System.out.println(e.nextElement());

  }
}
```